# Extend a Swagger Response Type at Swagger UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have the following like this below format for ***Example Value*** at Swagger UI:

```
{
  "Username": "string",
  "Interest": "string",
  "Position": "string"
}
```

And here is the following for the ***Response Body*** at Swagger UI:

```
{
  "ErrorCode": "0",
  "ErrorMessage": "Success.",
  "Result": [
    {
      "Username": "Test",
      "Interest": "Test",
      "Position": "Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is, how can I make the ***Example Value*** at Swagger UI to be like the ***Response Body*** at Swagger UI?

Here is the code that I am using:

**Model class:**

```
public class ActionResultExtended
{
   public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
   public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
   public object Result { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Interest { get; set; }
   public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller class:**

```
[ResponseType(typeof(User))] // This is where the Example Value comes from
public HttpResponseMessage GetUser()
{
   var userModel = new User
   {
       Username = "Test",
       Interest = "Test",
       Position = "Test"
   };

   var response = new ActionResultExtended()
   {
       ErrorCode = "0",
       ErrorMessage = "Success.",
       Result = userModel
   };

   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
}
```

I have tried the following, but it couldn't work as expected.

- [ResponseType(typeof(ActionResultExtended))]

How can I extend the ***ResponseType attribute*** from Web API? So that I can make it like the ***Response Body*** instead of the ***Example Value*** at Swagger UI.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of where the "Example Value" appears in Swagger UI?

Comment: Hi @Helen, sorry for late reply, but I have solved the issue by my own. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it by modifying my model class like this:

***Model class:***

```
public class ActionResultExtended
{
   public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
   public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
   public User Result { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Interest { get; set; }
   public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

And from the **ResponseType** attribute set it like this:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(ActionResultExtended))]
```

This way, the ***Example Value*** in Swagger UI will be same like ***Response Body*** in Swagger UI:

```
{
  "ErrorCode": "0",
  "ErrorMessage": "Success.",
  "Result": [
    {
      "Username": "Test",
      "Interest": "Test",
      "Position": "Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you.